# Lose variable expression after reload on Qlik Sense

Tags: variables, expression, qliksense

Suppose that I have a field x and I defined a variable vX to be an expression: =max(x). Also suppose that the maximum value of x is 10.

After a reload, Qlik Sense converts this expression on the variable to the value 10. This data is being reloaded every week and maybe the maximum could be 11 on another week. So if Qlik Sense makes this conversion, I can display wrong information and I don't want to change manually the expression every time to be the expression again.

Is there any way to keep the variable as an expression?

Comment: where are you defining the variable? in the script or in the UI?

Comment: @StefanStoichev  in the UI

Comment: hm. the variable it shouldnt be "converted" to its result in this case. If you set the variable content to be `max(x)` (remove the `=` sign) and then use the variable (in expression for example) like this: `$(vX)`. How is the result in this case?

Comment: Try `Let vX = 'max(x)';` in the load script.  Use the variable like `$(vX)` in a visualization.  If that doesn't work, then something strange is happening in your load script and you'll need to post it all here.